# Modifying the linux scheduler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, scheduling

I want to change specific parameters of the linux CFS scheduler like the virtual runtime of particular processes dynamically ( vruntime parameter in the sched_entity ). Is there any definite method to do this? I have already looked at commands like nice() and it won't serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can't change the **vruntime**, since it is maintained per task basis. Instead can check the current task's vruntime and other values per CPU basis, by issuing the below command                                                                                 "**#cat /proc/sched_debug**"